# Using WatiN to upload an avatar to YouTube

Tags: c#, youtube, watin

I am trying to automate the process of uploading a picture to set it as the avatar in YouTube.  So far I have the program logging into YouTube, going to the Channel page, and then click the "Edit Channel" button.

However, I am unable to get the file upload process to work.  Originally I used this code:

```
public FileUpload AvatarFileUpload
{
    get
    {
        return Document.FileUpload(Find.ByName("image") && Find.ById("image-upload-file-input"));
    }
}

AvatarFileUpload.Set(AvatarLocation);
```

This opened the file upload dialog box and entered the path to the imaget that needed to be uploaded however that didn't actually upload the photo.

I have used this code successfully to upload files to other websites so it isn't a problem with WatiN's FileUpload object.

It has to do with the fact that YouTube has a false button that hides the actual file form object and then uses jQuery or something to complete the process.

After doing some digging I can tell that the file upload object is in its own form and that form's action is a hidden iframe in the page.

So, I tried using this code to upload the file, submit that form, and then submit the main form but that doesn't work either.

```
public FileUpload AvatarFileUpload
{
    get
    {
        return Document.FileUpload(Find.ByName("image") && Find.ById("image-upload-file-input"));
    }
}

public Form ImageUploadForm
{
    get
    {
        return Document.Form(Find.ById("image-upload-form"));
    }
}

public Form ChannelsPageEditorForm
{
    get
    {
        return Document.Form(Find.ById("channels-page-editor-form"));
    }
}

AvatarFileUpload.Set(AvatarLocation);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
ImageUploadForm.Submit();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
ChannelsPageEditorForm.Submit();
```

I can't figure out how to get the actual avatar to update.  Does anyone have any advice/suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks!

P.S. I tried using WatiN recorder to see what they recommended but their solution didn't work either:

```
public Div BrandingEditorDiv
{
    get
    {
        return Document.Div(Find.ById("branding-editor-content"));
    }
}

public FileUpload AvatarFileUpload
{
    get
    {
        return Document.FileUpload(Find.ByName("image") && Find.ById("image-upload-file-input"));
    }
}

BrandingEditorDiv.Click();
AvatarFileUpload.Set(AvatarLocation);
```